# Using python with regex to match and mail

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a script that reads a log file that matches all items that have specific strings, i.e., today's date, a constant word, and the first number after the word. I am fairly new to Python, and have several issues;

1. How to match different groups using regular expressions without having one variable for each regex match 
   (var1 = `date` + `word` + `7`-something, var2 = `date` + `word` + `9`-something, and so on)
2. How to print the matches by group suffixed by another word, such as:

> Group 1
>
> `Geneva:`
>
> `2017-11-14: Word: 7712742 (1346134)`
>
> Group 2
>
> `Helsinki:`
>
> `2017-11-02: Word: 9124741 (912478)`

I would then like to write all of these matches and their suffixes to an e-mail.
The current way I have tried to tackle this is:

```
import time
import re
import glob

logpath = glob.glob('C:\\path\\to\\file*.log')[0]
readfile = open(logpath, "r")
daysdate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
regex = re.compile(daysdate + ".*[Word:] \d.+")
for line in readfile:
    req_id = regex.findall(line)
    for word in req_id:
        #this print shows all regex matches from the log file
        print(req_id,)
...
    mail.Body += "%s\n" % word 
    mail.Send()
```

Now, this prints out *all* matches for today's date and sends a mail to the desired user(s), but I am yet to find a way to do it as described above, short of creating and writing to several files, which then are read from. This feels like a very non-Pythonic way (and just bad practice for scripting overall).

Would one want go about this using several loops, such as for each match where the date is `date` + `word` + `7`-something, `print("Geneva:\n", req_id7)`, or are there other, better ways to solve this? The output of such an example gives:

```
Geneva: ['2017-11-15 04.03.18: Word: 78271187 (783342)'] 
Geneva: ['2017-11-15 04.03.19: Word: 75612345 (755491)'] 
Geneva: ['2017-11-15 04.03.22: Word: 70145678 (798640)']
```

Where I would like the output to be:

```
Geneva: 
['2017-11-15 04.03.18: Word: 78271187 (783342)']
['2017-11-15 04.03.19: Word: 75612345 (755491)']
['2017-11-15 04.03.22: Word: 70145678 (798640)']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to this problem was to create arrays and then loop through each regex, where matches were appended to their respective array, i.e.:

```
    geneva = []
    helsinki = []

    for line in readfile:
        for match in re.finditer(daysdate + r'.*Word: (7.{7}|9.{7})', line):
            gen.append(match.group(1))

        for match in re.finditer(daysdate + r'.*Word: (5.{7}|6.{7})', line):
            hel.append(match.group(1))
```

then using join to write out each region followed by their matches as such:

```
mail.Body = "Helsinki:\n%s\n" % ",\n".join(map(str,hel)) + \
"Geneva:\n%s\n" % ",\n".join(map(str,gen))
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but this could be one way to hack the problem:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

regex = re.compile(date + r': Word: (7*.|9.*)')
```

and then run the normal find command.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
print(req_id.replace("Geneva: ",""),)
```